# Laplace Transform of $\sin^{2018}(t)$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, laplace-transform

Hey so this question came up on a differential equations exam with regards to Laplace transforms and convolution integrals
$$
y''(t)+9y(t)=\sin^{2018}(t)
$$
$$
y(0)=y'(0)=0
$$

But I wasn't sure what the sine Laplace transform was. The professor said that the transform was just the sine transform, but raised to the power of 2018, however I am pretty sure that that is not the case.

How would someone go about doing this problem?

Comment: indeed that in not the case

Comment: Are you sure the professor didn't mean $\sin(2018 t)$? This is considerably easier to Laplace-Transform.

Comment: @AlexR., no it was definitely $\sin^{2018}(t)$. I feel like there is some competition math clever way to go about it, but I'm not sure how. Maybe some trig identities or the convolution integral?

Comment: Calling $I_n = L[\sin^n t]$ you can develop a difference equation such as $I_n = \phi_n(s) + p_n(s) I_{n-2}$ with $I_0 = L[1]$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking a look at [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions#Integrals_involving_exponential_and_trigonometric_functions), we have the recurring relation

$$ \int e^{-st}\sin^{n}(t)\ dt = -\frac{e^{-st}\sin^{n-1}(t)}{s^2+n^2}(s\sin t + n\cos t) + \frac{n(n-1)}{s^2+n^2}\int e^{-st}\sin^{n-2}(t)\ dt $$

Integrating from $0$ to $\infty$, we obtain
$$ L_n = \frac{n(n-1)}{s^2+n^2} L_{n-2} $$

where $L_n$ is the Laplace transform of $\sin^n(t)$. The base case is $L_0 = \dfrac{1}{s}$

Putting it all together
$$ L_{2018} = \frac{2018\cdot 2017}{s^2+2018^2}\cdot \frac{2016\cdot2015}{s^2+2016^2}\cdots \frac{1}{s} = \frac{2018!}{s} \prod\limits_{k=1}^{1009} \frac{1}{\big(s^2 + (2k)^2\big)} $$

This leads to the solution 
$$ Y(s) = \frac{2018!}{s(s^2+9)} \prod\limits_{k=1}^{1009} \frac{1}{\big(s^2 + (2k)^2\big)} $$

which you can reverse transform by taking the convolution of $\sin^{2018}(t)$ and $\mathcal L \{\frac{1}{s^2+9}\} = \frac13 \sin 3t$

$$ y(t) = \frac13 \int_0^t \sin^{2018}(\tau)\sin \big(3(t-\tau)\big) d\tau $$

and using more recurrence relations

Comment: Thank you! It turns out to solve this problem on the exam, they just wanted us to leave the transform in terms of the transform, and then end the result with a definite integral.